# saving a php search to a database table

Tags: java, html

I was just wondering if anyone can help me, i've been struggling with this for a few days.
Basically I am doing a dynamic search of a backend php database and want to use the searched information to add to another table. EG: to record data they have searched.
The search is working fine but when i click insert record the values for the 2 items searched is null in the php table.

I'd appreciate some help. My php knowledge is basic.
thanks

Comment: by the way you cant code php using java :D

Comment: Maybe you are talking about a MySQL database? Or a small server one? Php is not a dbms

Comment: This just proves my knowledge. I am using dreamweaver and xampp php and have them both connecting but the search is saving as null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic idea of what you could do if you're trying to "Save" their searches into the database. First you will make a variable called '$search_string' and then in that first working function you made to search for things in the database you will put that same string inside of the variable($search_string). Then after that you will put that string int othe database along with the users ID(If you have it) and the string they searched for like this.

```
// So this with be the variable holding the search string that the user searched for E.G Beyonce
$search_string = "";

// This is the function you already made to search for that string ($search_string) in the database

function search(){
     .... // This is the search code you already made

$search_string = 'The variable thats holding the search string the person sent. It should be a $_POST variable or a variable you already made';

// Now just put the string into the database like so

$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO searches (uid,search_string) VALUES ('". $uid . "', '".$search_string."')"); 

 }
```

Then after that you should have it inside of your database. Now i have no idea how you have your database tables set up but thats the theory behind what you're trying to do. Also keep in mind that you should change your "mysql_connect" parameters to your own database  parameters but you probably wont need it because you might have a connection open already that you can use. Hope it helps